# running a class with main from a servlet in j2EE

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, servlets

How to (or can i) run a class with main() from a servlet??

i want to take input from a html page and insert data into a database using hibernate.

-i have an annotated class.

-a class having main(), running which inserts the data into the database.

-and a servlet with post method code:

```
String input_from_html=request.getParameter("input_from_html");
```

I need to put the data 'input_from_html' to the class with main() and run the class,which should happen once the submit button in the html page is pressed.

Comment: Care to explain *why* you would want to do that? What's so special about that class's main that you cannot just call its methods directly?

Comment: actually i dnt have any idea.. i tried to do so..it throws some exception i didnt understand..so instead i put that inside the main fn and run it manually which did work.....running on the server just not working..

Comment: Try solving the actual problem, the one indicated by the exception. If you want help with the exception, create a new question about that. My experience has learned that by what I call "dancing around the problem" you only make your problem bigger in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea, because you want your database insert to be within a transaction so it can either commit or rollback as appropriate. Running the insert as an executable triggered by a request to a servlet means there won't be any transaction that's initiated by the incoming request.

Comment: so how should i approach?

Comment: Take a read of the Transactions section in the EE tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions.htm#BNCIH

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the main like any normal static method.

For Ex,

```
class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]){

  }
}
```

You can call this main method inside servlet like :

```
class AServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void service(...){
      MainClass.main(...);
  }
}
```